# SQL sum on a list of keys and making duplicate

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I couldn't figure how to do this. I would like to sum a coulmn called `total_spending` for similar pairs (`vin`, `action`) and have an output like the example:

**Input**

```
action  dealer_name   vin    Total_spending reference month year 
A1      D1            V1         T1             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T2             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T3             R2     M2    Y2
A3      D1            V1         T4             R1     M1    Y1
A4      D1            V2         T5             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D1            V2         T6             R1     M1    Y1
A1      D1            V1         T7             R2     M2    Y2
A4      D3            V2         T8             R2     M2    Y2
A1      D1            V1         T9             R3     M3    Y3
A3      D2            V2         T10            R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V1         T11            R2     M2    Y2
```

**Output**

```
action  dealer_name   vin    Total_spending reference month year 
A1      D1            V1         T1 + T7 + T9   R1     M1    Y1
A1      D2            V1         T1 + T7 + T9   R1     M1    Y1
A1      D3            V1         T1 + T7 + T9   R1     M1    Y1
A2      D1            V2         T2 + T3        R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T2 + T3        R1     M1    Y1
A3      D1            V1         T4 + T11       R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V1         T4 + T11       R1     M1    Y1
A4      D1            V2         T5 + T8        R1     M1    Y1
A4      D3            V2         T5 + T8        R1     M1    Y1
A2      D1            V2         T6             R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V2         T10            R1     M1    Y1
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    action,
    dealer_name,
    vin,
    SUM(total_spending) as total_spending,
    reference,
    year,
    issue_date,
    country_code
FROM table_name
GROUP BY
    action,
    dealer_name,
    vin,
    reference,
    year,
    issue_date,
    country_code
```

Comment: How you can choose the first of a group depends on the database. Which database are you using? (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, ...)

Comment: Hadoop Hive @Andomar

Comment: @Jinx_man . . . I see no obvious difference between this and your previous question.  If there is one, please *highlight* the difference so it is clear why the previous answer does not work.  You should also accept answers to the questions that you ask.